# Making a grid with a specific interval

Tags: r, r-grid

I am new to R but I need to make a plot with a grid behind it the grid must have an interval of 0.004 to 0.08 in 1000 steps. I already have the sequence for the interval but I have no idea how to get the grid and the axis right?
With `plot(data)` I get nice the data as points and with lines I get a nice line with it. I tried `grid(NA,1000,lwd=2)` but this only gets me the grid lines in a plot. `axis(1, xaxp = seq(0.004, 0.08,by = (0.08-0.004)/1000), las=2)` when I try this I get the error graphical parameter `xaxp` has the wrong length so I am at a loss.

Comment: You should probably use `at` instead of `xaxp`. Also use `length=1000` instead of `by=(0.08-0.004)/1000)`.

Comment: what kind of output you are interested in? a grid frame? an image grid? COuld you provide further detail or a link to an example?